# Java: Array syntax error when defining a new Rectangle

Tags: java, android, arrays

Ok, so I really can't figure this one out. I defined an array, playerPos, like this:

```
int[] playerPos = new int[]{32, 32};
```

and the first number is the x value, second is the y value. But, when I try to use it to define a rectangle, I get a syntax error here:

```
        for (int x = 0 ; x < 64; x++) {
        for (int y = 0 ; y < 64; y++) {
            switch(map[x][y]) {
            case 1:
                mapRects[x][y] = new Rect(x - playerPos[0])*64, (y - playerPos[1])*64, ((x - playerPos[0])*64)+64, ((y - playerPos[1])*64)+64);
                break;

            case 2:
                mapRects[x][y] = new Rect(x - playerPos[0])*64, ((y - playerPos[1])*64)-64, ((x - playerPos[0])*64)+64, ((y - playerPos[1])*64)+64);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Wherever I say new Rect(), it gives me a syntax error on all the commas saying

```
Syntax error on token ",", [ expected
```

and on the last number, it says

```
Syntax error, insert "]" to complete Expression
```

I have no idea what is wrong. Help?

Answer (score 5):

It is a parentheses problem:

```
new Rect(x - playerPos[0])*64 ...
```

You probably need to add an opening one like this:

```
new Rect((x - playerPos[0])*64 ...
```

Comment: Wow, that is probably the dumbest mistake I have ever made in my life. Even more, I didn't notice. Thanks so much!

Comment: Everyone does it. Multiple times. The only trick I can think of that helps is to write parentheses in a pairs when you open the first one. If you do that every time, you'll never go screwy. So type str(), first, then add the expression inside, say str(10.0/2.1). The only annoyance is having to cursor back. Some IDEs auto open parentheses and brackets in pairs, but I find them mostly annoying with where they then place the cursor. I use vim. Vim rocks.

Comment: Oh and maybe you want to ACCEPT THE ANSWER, spng453. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a parenthesis on your Rect.